# Oracle LAG Function for each unique row

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following query:

```
SELECT
        EEEV_EMPL_ID, 
        EEEV_DT, 
        EEEV_CCTR_ID, 
        LAG(EEEV_CCTR_ID, 1, ' ') OVER(ORDER BY EEEV_EMPL_ID DESC, EEEV_END_DT ASC) AS prev
FROM 
        CDAS.VDWHEEEV1 eeev1
ORDER BY 
        EEEV_EMPL_ID
```

So the table can have multiple rows for each EEEV_EMPL_ID.  I want to lag for each group of unique empl_id's.  I dont want to lag from one empl_id to another.  So if it is the last row of the group, the lag value should be Null or something.  Right now it is just lagging to the next row, even if it is a different empl_id.  How do I accomplish that.  I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want `partition by`:

```
    LAG(EEEV_CCTR_ID, 1, ' ') OVER (PARTITION BY EEEV_EMPL_ID ORDER BY EEEV_END_DT ASC) AS prev
```

Comment: Yup, that works, it was the partition by that did the trick, thank you so much.